# How to save Spire.doc file to custom location in "Java"

Tags: java, save, location, doc, spire

I am working on printing project. I am using Spire.doc package to write docx file but I don't know how to save that file to different location

```
doc.saveToFile(filename, fileFormat.Docx_2013);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where are the API docs for that software?

Comment: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.Doc-for-Java/Program-Guide/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide-Content-for-Java.html

Comment: Fortunately now I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.saveToFile("C:\\Users\\"  + System.getProperty("user.name"+ filename, FileFormat.Docx_2013);
```